# Análise recursiva de um vetor

Tags: c, recursão, array

QUESTÃO:

Escreva uma função **recursiva** que analisa os elementos de um vetor e retorna um dentre os seguintes códigos:

0 Elementos desordenados
1 Elementos ordenados em ordem crescente
2 Elementos constantes
3 Elementos ordenados em ordem decrescente

```
int AnalisaVetor(int V[], int n);
```

Use o protótipo acima onde “n” indica o número de elementos presentes no vetor.

Exemplos:

```
Para V={1,2,2,5,6,6,7,8,8,9} retorna código 1.
Para V={20,15,11,10,8,8,5,2} retorna código 3.
Para V={1,20,2,5,6,6,7,80,9} retorna código 0.
Para V={8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8} retorna código 2.
```

Tentando resolver a questão eu cheguei no seguinte código:

```
int analisa(int v[], int n)
{
    if(v[n-1] == v[n-2])
    {
        if(n == 2)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        else
        {
            return analisa(v, n-1);
        }
    }
    else if(v[n-1] < v[n-2])
    {
        if(n == 2)
        {
            return 3;
        }
        else
        {
            return analisa(v, n-1);
        }
    }
    else if(v[n-1] > v[n-2])
    {
        if(n==2)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return analisa(v, n-1);
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Entretanto, ele não funciona de maneira esperada quando, por exemplo, o dois primeiros elementos do vetor são iguais e o resto segue uma sequência crescente ou decrescente. Outro caso no qual não há o funcionamento esperado é quando o vetor está desordenado. Como posso corrigir esses erros?

Comment: O algoritmo precisa ser recursivo (o exercício pede isso?) ou você que julga que usar recursão é uma boa saída? Se o exercício pede o uso de recursão, ok, mas se não pede, é melhor não usar.

Comment: O exercício pede isso.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As tuas condições estão incompletas.

Um array de `N` elementos é composto de números crescentes quando o array mais pequeno com os primeiros `N - 1` é composto de números crescentes **e** o penúltimo elemento do array não é maior que o último. Ou seja

```
// chamar função com array de 0 elementos é Comportamento Não Definido
int analisa(int *v, size_t n) {
    if (n == 1) return 2; // um array com um elemento é "constante"
    int tmp = analisa(v, n - 1); // analisa array mais pequeno recursivamente
    switch (tmp) {
        case 0: // array mais pequeno desordenado
            return 0;
            break;
        case 1: // array mais pequeno crescente
            if (v[n - 2] > v[n - 1]) return 0; // desordenado
            return 1;
            break;
        case 2: // array mais pequeno constante
            if (v[n - 2] < v[n - 1]) return 1; // crescente
            if (v[n - 2] > v[n - 1]) return 3; // decrescente
            return 2;
            break;
        case 3: // array mais pequeno decrescente
            if (v[n - 2] < v[n - 1]) return 0; // desordenado
            return 3;
            break;
        default: // erro
            return -1; // erro
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Era bom um exemplo no ideone.

Comment: @JorgeB. http://ideone.com/4D4BUz obrigado pela sugestão